# In C++, does a vector occupy successive memory slots?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

If I define `vector<double> v;` does this vector occupy successive memory slots? If it occupies successive memory slots, what would happen if I add some new element to this vector while there is not enough memory slots right after the last element?

Comment: Yes. It will reallocate the elements if they won't fit in the currently allocated space.

Comment: this is called contiguous storage, and there are two standard containers that guarantee it: vector and array. In C++17 they'll add an iterator with this guarantee: ContiguousIterator.

Comment: That kind of storage allows you to retrieve elements in such data structures in O(1) complexity (very fast).

Comment: @Spidey It also happens to be C compatible (by passing the pointer retrieved from .data())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

> The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets on regular pointers to elements.